# Is there an OnClick function for ContentControl

Tags: vba, ms-word, onclick

I'm incredibly new to Visual Basic, but have been tasked with trying to adjust a function from an old word document so that it is more responsive.

Essentially, the document has a series of checkboxes that when clicked, hide or display various elements of the document using content controls. Currently, a user has to check a checkbox, and then click out of the checked checkbox for the hide/display to happen, but ideally, I wanted this to be instantaneous with the initial click/check.

I'm just wanting to know i there's some kind of OnClick or something I can substitute ContentControlOnExit so that it is more responsive.

```
Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox4" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP2").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox5" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP1").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox2" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign1").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign2").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox3" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("note").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this wasn't too vague or unclear, and thanks for any pointers or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContentControlOnEnter, just select Document on the drop down of the VBA editor right above the code window, and then select ContentControlOnEnter, and copy the code from ContentControlOnExit into ContentControlOnEnter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an OnClick event for content controls.

Using the OnEnter and OnExit events only really works when you actually click on the control after clicking elsewhere, click elsewhere after clicking on the control, or tab in or out of the control. If you hover over the control and click more than once, none of those fire.

If you map your content control to an element in a CustomXMLPart, then you get some more options. At first sight it looks as if you can use the ContentControlBeforeStoreUpdate event (clicking on a checkbox will result in an immediate update of the mapped element's value). But that doesn't actually work in this case because Word does not let you access the parts of the object model you need when executing that event. (There is in fact a way to work around this problem using a Timer and other things but I can only give a link to that, and AIUI that's discouraged here).

You can use the CustomXmlPart's events instead.

Based on your code, the following code (re)creates a suitable CustomXmlPart (CXP) and connects the checkboxes to it. You should only need to run it once.

```
Sub recreateCXPandMapCCs()
' Specify a namespace for your CXP
Const myns As String = "checkboxevents"
Dim ccs As Word.ContentControls
Dim cxp As Office.CustomXMLPart
Dim cxps As Office.CustomXMLParts
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim s As String
s = ""
s = s & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "<checkboxvalues xmlns='" & myns & "'>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "  <checkbox1value/>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "  <checkbox2value/>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "  <checkbox3value/>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "  <checkbox4value/>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "  <checkbox5value/>" & vbCrLf
s = s & "</checkboxvalues>"

With ActiveDocument
  ' select and delete any existing CXPs with the specified namespace
  Set cxps = .CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(myns)
  For Each cxp In cxps
    cxp.Delete
  Next
  Set cxps = Nothing
  ' Create a new CXP
  Set cxp = .CustomXMLParts.Add(s)
  ' Connect your checkboxes. There are various ways you could do this,
  ' but here we're relying on a consistent naming convention.
  ' and the knowledge that Word will assign the prefix name "ns0" to
  ' our namespace
  For i = 1 To 5
    .SelectContentControlsByTitle("Checkbox" & CStr(i)).Item(1).XMLMapping.SetMapping "//ns0:checkbox" & CStr(i) & "value[1]", , cxp
  Next
  Set cxp = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, unlike handling Content Control events, where you can just put the event handlers in the ThisDocument module and Word fires them, to set up Word to fire these events you have to run some code when the document is created or opened, and preferably run some code when the document is closed. In this example, you can put the following code in your ThisDocument module, and manually run the linkupCxpEvents and unlinkCxpEvents procedures to start and stop event processing.

```
Option Explicit
' This needs to have the same namespace name as you
' use to create the CXP
Const myns As String = "checkboxevents"

Dim WithEvents cxp As CustomXMLPart

' You might call this sub from an AutoOpen macro, Document.Open event etc.
Sub linkupCxpEvents()
Set cxp = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(myns).Item(1)
End Sub

Sub unlinkCxpEvents()
Set cxp = Nothing
End Sub

' Notice that we don't actually need to know the checkbox Titles or Tags,
' just the names of the elements they are connected to in the data store
Private Sub cxp_NodeAfterReplace(ByVal OldNode As Office.CustomXMLNode, ByVal NewNode     As Office.CustomXMLNode, ByVal InUndoRedo As Boolean)
Select Case NewNode.ParentNode.BaseName
  Case "checkbox1value"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
  Case "checkbox2value"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign1").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign2").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
  Case "checkbox3value"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("note").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
  Case "checkbox4value"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP2").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
  Case "checkbox5value"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP1").Range.Font.Hidden = CBool(NewNode.NodeValue)
  Case Else
End Select
End Sub
```